# Windows Live Messenger: stop sharing a link

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I once shared a link in Windows Live Messenger, but now there doesn't seem to be an option to disable this link from being shared.

I can merely share a new link.

Any ways to disable this link sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the box to share something new, there is a button that says Share.  Leave that box empty and just click on Share.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in your "status" area? You should be able to get to the point where you can edit the text in your status area and use the backspace or delete key to remove it to be blank..

Comment: The status area allows you to set text and to share a link at the same time. I do not have any text set, so I cannot delete anything. There is a link shared however, but it cannot be deleted, only changed.